# Problema usando Eclipse para Java y C++

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, namespace, actualizacion

Hace ya tiempo que programo en C++, Java y Python; y me he acostumbrado bastante a Dev-C++, Eclipse y PyCharm, pero en este momento estoy en un aprieto.

### **Primero, Java:**

En cuanto a Java, venía usando la versión del 2017 sin problemas de ningún tipo. Justamente hoy lo actualicé a su última versión (2019-12), y decidí probarlo con proyectos que tenía guardados anteriormente.

Los programas que hice se ejecutan perfectamente, funcionan exactamente igual a como lo hacían con la versión del 2017, pero en la pantalla de errores se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Errores obtenidos]

Realmente nunca me había topado con algo así. Son muchísimos errores de ese tipo uno atrás de otro. No sé por dónde empezar para solucionarlo (aclaro nuevamente que los programas desarrollados en Java funcionan perfectamente y se ejecutan exactamente igual que antes, simplemente se muestran esos errores molestos y no quiero hacer de cuenta que no pasa nada).
No sé cómo empezar a buscar la solución a un error de este tipo porque no lo comprendo. Cada mensaje de error es absurdamente largo. Dejo uno como referencia:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.14.0.I20191210-0610
java.version=1.8.0_241
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_AR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data file:/C:/Users/fran-/eclipse-workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench
Error
Wed Feb 19 14:41:27 ART 2020
Failed to evaluate: WithExpression [variable=selection, children=[IterateExpression [type=AND, children=[<test property="canDelete" plug-in activation: lazy/>]]]]

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property org.eclipse.tcf.te.launch.ui.model.canDelete to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.IterateExpression.evaluate(IterateExpression.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$1.changed(EvaluationService.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.handleSelectionChanged(SelectionService.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.SelectionService.lambda$0(SelectionService.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$1.run(SelectionAggregator.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.notifyListeners(SelectionAggregator.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator.access$2(SelectionAggregator.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.lambda$0(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.RunAndTrack.runExternalCode(RunAndTrack.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionAggregator$5.changed(SelectionAggregator.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.SelectionServiceImpl.setSelection(SelectionServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.selectionChanged(CompatibilityPart.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$1.run(Viewer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1170)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleSelect(CommonViewer.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1199)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4175)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3988)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3587)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de qué se pudo haber desconfigurado o qué tengo que actualizar/descargar/chequear?

### **Segundo, C++:**

Dejando de lado el problema anterior, intenté usar Eclipse para programar en lenguaje C++ (me he acostumbrado mucho a la interfaz de Eclipse y quería mantanerme con un solo programa para ambas cosas).

Fui a: "Help" >> "Install New Software..." y descargué los paquetes para C++.
Configuré Eclipse como lo indican en miles de tutoriales con MinGW GCC ó Cygwin GCC, pero no consigo hacer que me reconozca el namespace "std". Obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Errores obtenidos]

Cuando posiciono el cursor sobre "std" obtengo el error:

```
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
```

Y del mismo modo, obtengo errores muy similares (lógicamente) sobre todo elemento que pertenezca al namespace "std".

He seguido paso a paso aproximadamente 10 tutoriales en todos los idiomas para solucionar este problema de Eclipse con C++ y ninguno me ha funcionado; algunos hasta me dan más problemas que soluciones.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos.

### **EDIT :**

Pude solucionar el problema con Java reinstalando tanto el JDK como el JRE con su última versión y reconfigurando las variables de entorno del sistema.

El problema con C++ aún no lo pude solucionar.

Comment: Buenas, en cuanto a tu segundo problema , es difícil configurarlo para java y c++, te recomiendo tener eclipses separados, te ahorrara dolores de cabeza. Y el primero es solo un error repetido constantemente. Seguramente porque el proyecto se creo con una versión antigua de eclipse, y en la ejecución del proyecto no tiene todo lo que la nueva versión espera. Yo no me preocuparía, seguramente creando un nuevo proyecto en esta versión y copiando el código de esos proyectos ya no se reproduciría.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario. Lo de Java pude solucionarlo y, efectivamente, eran errores de compatibildad de versiones de Eclipse. Por otro lado, descargué el instalador de Eclipse para instalar la versión de "C/C++ Developer IDE" e igualmente no me funcionó. Seguiré intentando. Nuevamente, ¡muchas gracias por las sugerencias!

Comment: Denada @Fran Bonino pase por lo mismo xD

Comment: Puede que no te funcionase esa instalación, porque por defecto pone el mismo directorio en el que tendrías instalado el de Java, posiblemente ... cambiando el nombre del directorio ya no te de conflictos. Yo por ejemplo tengo /home/Programas/eclipse/cpp-eclipse y /home/Programas/eclipse/java-eclipse.  A la hora de hacer las instalaciones por separado. En ambos la ruta dada por defecto seria .../eclipse/eclipse y te copia ficheros de una instalación en la otra

Comment: Hice lo que me sugeriste y ayudó muchísimo. Si bien seguía teniendo pequeñas advertencias en cuanto a los **'include'**, un error con el **'makefile'** y el error **_"undefined reference to 'WinMain'_**", lo pude solucionar reinstalando Cygwin con otros paquetes que no había descargado con anterioridad y reconfigurando un poco las especificaciones de Eclipse para C++. Ahora todo funciona perfectamente. ¡¡Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado y que pudieses resolver tus problemas.